# Why can a client socket detect a server socket close, but not vice-versa?

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp, wifi

In my tcp implementation of a client-server relationship, I have noticed only the client socket is able to detect when the server socket closes.  Without the aid of a heartbeat, the server socket cannot detect a client disconnect.

Why is this one sided?  Are there alternatives to heartbeats to detect if the connection is still live from a server socket standpoint? Links appreciated!

Comment: Because you have a bug in your (invisible) code. It isn't one-sided.

Answer (score 2):

This is no such limit with client server. This means your implementation must be either wrong or you make the wrong assumptions.

A close from the peer with TCP/IP can only be detected by an application:

- If the local application tries to read and the read fails because the connection was closed by the peer.
- If the local application tries to write and the write fails because the connection was closed by the peer.

If you neither try to read nor write you cannot detect a connection close from the peer. It does not matter if you are client or server.

Answer (score 0):

You need to distinguish between a TCP connection closing vs a "disconnect". What does "disconnect" mean?

A connection close is part of the TCP protocol, so if one side or the other closes it's connection then the opposite side will receive a packet to indicate it.

However, if one side just disappears then the other side has no way of knowing that.

The TCP protocol was designed to be reliable in hostile communication environments and it will not normally decide a connection is closed just because it has not heard from the other side for a while.

This problem can be mitigated by setting the [SO_KEEPALIVE](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/SocketOptions.html#SO_KEEPALIVE) option on the socket.